# JavaScript How to let user type variable in text box solve equation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simple equation solver that involves division. I have two text boxes, One for "Mass" and one for "Element". I want to create a variable "H" and set it equal to 1, that way when the user types in "2" in the mass box and "H" in the element box, the output will say "1".

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="GramsToMolesContainer"><div id="GramMolesText">
<font size=3>Grams To Moles</font></div>
<form>
Grams : <input type="text" id="GramsChoice" /><br>
Element : <input type="text" id="ElementChoice" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="GramstoMoles()" Value="Convert" />
</form>
<p>Molar Mass : <br>
<span id = "resultMolarMass"></span>
</p>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
function GramstoMoles()
{
var H = 1;

GramsState = document.getElementById("GramsChoice").value;

ElementState = 
document.getElementById("ElementChoice").value;

document.getElementById("resultMolarMass").innerHTML 
= GramsState / ElementState;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to create a dictionary.
this is how your function should look. every time that you want to add an element - create a new key-value pair.

```
function GramstoMoles()
{
var elements = {h:1, he:2};

GramsState = document.getElementById("GramsChoice").value;

ElementState = 
document.getElementById("ElementChoice").value;

document.getElementById("resultMolarMass").innerHTML 
= parseInt(GramsState) / elements[ElementState];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working snippet of your code!

If you wan to set `H` as an inital value of some box, do

`var ElementState = document.getElementById("ElementChoice").value = H;` before you call the function.

```js
function GramstoMoles (){

var H = 1;
var GramsState = document.getElementById("GramsChoice").value;
var ElementState = document.getElementById("ElementChoice").value;
document.getElementById("resultMolarMass").innerHTML = GramsState / ElementState;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="GramsToMolesContainer"><div id="GramMolesText">
<font size=3>Grams To Moles</font></div>
<form>
Grams : <input type="text" id="GramsChoice" /><br>
Element : <input type="text" id="ElementChoice" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="GramstoMoles()" Value="Convert" />
</form>
<p>Molar Mass : <br>
<span id = "resultMolarMass"></span>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the `var element` and `var grams` ,

```
var elements = ['H','He','Li','Be',...];
var atomicmasses = [1,4,6,9,.....];
var molarmass = molarmasses[elements.indexOf(element)];
var mole = grams/molarmass;
```